# Query WordPress Database and Post HTML Table

Tags: html, sql

I'm looking for some help building the base code to query my WP database, retrieve a table and then post this on a page. There seems to be a lot on the web to assist with this, however with limited php/sql coding background I'm finding it hard to wade through everything. I find things easier to learn by reverse engineering and building from there.

I've downloaded the plugin **PHP code snippets (Insert PHP)** which gives me the ability to add php code into posts (being deprecated in next version) or shortcodes.

I believe the following code should be sufficient to query the wp_post table and return the table data in an array.

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' LIMIT 10');
```

What I want to be able to do from here is generate a html table in a WP page using this data. How would I go about this?

Once I've got this base code sorted I can build off this and develop what I need.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

```
$html= "<table>";    
foreach($result as $r){
  $html .="<tr>";
  $html .="<td>".$r->post_title."</td>";
  $html .="<td><a href='".get_the_permalink($r->ID)"'>".$r->post_title."</a></td>";
  $html .="</tr>";
}
$html .="</table>";
echo $html;
```

To avoid the depreacated usage of PHP code snippets you can wrap it in a shortcode and use anywhere in a page/post content editor

```
function Stack_308511_post_grid( $atts ) {
 $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
  'limit' => 10,
  ), $atts,'limits'  );

 global $wpdb;
 $html = "";

 $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix.'posts LIMIT '.$atts['limit']);
 $count = $wpdb->num_rows;
 if($count >0){
  $html .="<table>";    
  foreach($result as $r){
    $html .="<tr>";
    $html .="<td>".$r->post_title."</td>";
    $html .="<td><a href='".get_the_permalink($r->ID)."'>".$r->post_title."</a></td>";
    $html .="</tr>";
   }
  $html .="</table>";
}

return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'postGrid', 'Stack_308511_post_grid' );
```

So in the html editor you can use

- **[postGrid]** which will use the default 10 post limit or i.e.
- **[postGrid limit=20]** which will pick the latest 20 posts

Comment: So, If I understand this correctly, The first code section should print a html table from the code I had in my question? The second code block is a consolidated (all in 1) "query and print" shortcode solution?

Comment: yes correct..try it it's not fully testedPlease note that the query in your code :`$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' LIMIT 10');` is wrong it should be `$wpdb->prefix.'posts'` instead of $wpdb->posts

Comment: Cool, I'm getting a result print out using `$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix.'posts' . ' LIMIT 10');` and then `print_r($result);`. So I know the query is working. Just struggling to get anything to print out with the `$html` code. I'll take some time to work through it and see what I need to change. You've been a huge help, thankyou so much

Comment: But why do you query posts using raw SQL?

Comment: quite newbie here, just to ask : why downvote?